# ¿Cómo obtener los datos de un documento y la colección que tiene este documento?

Tags: angular, firebase, angular7, angular6

Estoy tratando de obtener los datos de un documento, y también este documento tiene un campo que es una colección. ¿Cómo puedo obtener todos esos datos? mi documento tiene las siguientes propiedades:

Yo uso el paquete angularFire.

nombre: String, apellido: String, elementos: Colección.

Este documento es de una colección de usuarios:

Mi código:

```javascript
collection('users')
 .Doc(ID)
 .collection('items')
 .SnapshotChanges()
 .Subscribe(val => console.log('val', val))
 //pero este retorno [{type: { },carga útil:{}},{},....]
```

Intenté cambiar snapshotChange a ValueChanges, pero eso solo me trae datos de mi colección interna (items).

gracias

Comment: Puedes consultar la documentación de angularFire (https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md#snapshotchanges)

Comment: Esta respuesta te es de ayuda? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55304470/angular-firestore-collection-snapshot-changes